# CloudKit Server to Server Backup with Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, cloudkit, cloudkit-web-services

I would like to run a daily backup of my App's CloudKit (iCloud) container to Google Cloud.
Apple have announced that CloudKit now supports server to server requests but I was wondering if this is possible to perform backups and if so, how?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

CloudKit.js only supports access to public database, but not private database.
You can check  [Apple's sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/CloudAtlas/Listings/Node_node_client_s2s_index_js.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014599-Node_node_client_s2s_index_js-DontLinkElementID_22) or [raywenderlich's tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/135551/cloudkit-js-tutorial) on how to do this.